# Get CSV file header using apache commons

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

I have been looking for the past 2 hours for a solution to my problem in vain. I'am trying to read a CSV File using [Apache commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) ,I am able to read the whole file but my problem is how to extract only the header of the CSV in an array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, first record read by `CSVParser` will always be a header record, e.g. in the below example:

```
CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(FILE_HEADER_MAPPING);
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("file");
CSVParser csvFileParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, csvFileFormat);
List csvRecords = csvFileParser.getRecords();
```

`csvRecords.get(0)` will return the header record.

Comment: This is an impossible answer.  It appears to have been cribbed from https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/apache/commons/csv-commons/writeread-csv-files-with-apache-commons-csv-example/.  Note that `FILE_HEADER_MAPPING` contains the header.. which is what the original question was asking for.

Comment: As @daveloyall was pointing out, the answer does not address the original question as the code provided assumes that the header fields are already available in FILE_HEADER_MAPPING. I downvoted so better answers can bubble to the top.

Answer (score 10):

I looked everywhere and even the solution above didn't work.
For anyone else with this issue, this does.

```
Iterable<CSVRecord> records;
Reader in = new FileReader(fileLocation);
records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader().withSkipHeaderRecord(false).parse(in);
Set<String> headers = records.iterator().next().toMap().keySet();
```

Note that your use of `.next()` has consumed one row of the CSV.

Answer (score 7):

Since Apache Commons CSV v1.9.0, the `withSkipHeaderRecord()` & the `withFirstRecordAsHeader()` methods are deprecated.  A builder interface is provided.  Use it thusly:

```java
CSVFormat.DEFAULT.builder()
    .setHeader()
    .setSkipHeaderRecord(true)
    .build();
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but not complete. It sent me looking for more. I think you should add something like`Reader in = new FileReader(fileName, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` and `CSVFormat cSVFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.builder().setHeader().setSkipHeaderRecord(false).build();` and `Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVParser.parse(in, cSVFormat);`

Answer (score 6):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(br, CSVFormat.EXCEL.withFirstRecordAsHeader());

List<String> headers = parser.getHeaderNames();
```

This worked for me. The last line is what you need, extracts the headers found by the parser into a List of Strings.

Comment: CSVFormat.EXCEL is not working for me at all. Can you take a look at this and help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67964627/how-to-read-excel-xlsx-multipartfile-using-apache-csv-parser-current-approac

@Justin

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin:

```kotlin
val reader = File(path).bufferedReader()
val records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader()
    .withIgnoreHeaderCase()
    .withTrim()
    .parse(reader)

println(records.headerNames)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import org.apache.commons.csv.*;

public static String[] headersInCSVFile (String csvFilePath) throws IOException {
        //reading file
        CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT;
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(csvFilePath);
        CSVParser csvFileParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, csvFileFormat);
        List csvRecords = csvFileParser.getRecords();
        
        //Obtaining first record and splitting that into an array using delimiters and removing unnecessary text
        String[] headers = csvRecords.get(0).toString().split("[,'=\\]\\[]+");
        String[] result = new String[headers.length - 6];
        for (int i = 6; i < headers.length; i++) {
            //.replaceAll("\\s", "") removes spaces
            result[i - 6] = headers[i].replaceAll("\\s", "");
        } 
        return result;
}
```