# How to read Excel(.xlsx) Multipartfile using Apache CSV Parser?. Current approach not working with CSVFormat set to EXCEL

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, csv

I'm trying to read records for both CSV as well as Excel format using Apache CSVParser. Below is my approach for the same.

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream(),
                                                                              StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            CSVParser parser;
            String extension = StringUtils.getFilenameExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());
            logger.info("Extension Detected : {}", extension);
            if (extension != null && extension.equals("xlsx")) {
                parser = new CSVParser(reader,
                                       CSVFormat.EXCEL.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withTrim());
            } else if(extension != null && extension.equals("csv")){
                parser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader()
                                                                .withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim());
            } else {
                throw new InvalidRequestException(Collections.singletonList(INVALID_EXTENSION));
            }
            logger.info("Records parsed successfully for file : {}", file.getOriginalFilename());
            return parser.getRecords();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new FileReadException(e);
        }
```

This is working for CSV Files but not for Excel. Parser is not able to read the records properly. Here's the debugged value of parser.

[image]

I feel it's related to reusableToken because in case of CSV, Token Type is TOKEN , But in case of Excel it's EORecord.

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache CSVParser can't parse Excel files, only csv files. Using the `CSVFormat.EXCEL` parameter just tells CSVParser that the csv file was created/exported using Excel.

To read xls & xlsx files you need to use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/).